# i want to share multimedia files and want to store in interanl memory

Tags: java, android

I am using this code please suggest me any link and any kind of books related to my question. this code is working fine but it is used to send only text after fetching from a textview between two devices using wifi direct.

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String msg=writeMsg.getText().toString();
                sendRecieve.write(msg.getBytes());
            }
        });
```

```
    public class  ServerClas extends Thread{
        Socket socket;
        ServerSocket serverSocket;

         @Override
         public void run() {
             try{
                 serverSocket=new ServerSocket(8888);
                 socket=serverSocket.accept();
                 sendRecieve=new SendRecieve(socket);
                 sendRecieve.start();
             }catch (IOException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
     public class SendRecieve extends Thread{
        private Socket socket;
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private OutputStream outputStream;
        public SendRecieve(Socket skt){
            socket=skt;
            try{
                inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
                outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();

            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

         @Override
         public void run() {
             byte[]  buffer=new byte[1024];
             int bytes;
             while (socket!=null){
                 try{
                     bytes=inputStream.read(buffer);
                     if( bytes>0){
                         handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ,bytes,-1,buffer).sendToTarget();
                     }
                 }catch(IOException e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         }
         public void write(byte[] bytes){
             try {
                 outputStream.write(bytes);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }


         }
     }
     public  class ClientClass extends Thread{
        Socket socket;
        String hostAdd;



         public ClientClass(InetAddress hostAddress){
            hostAdd=hostAddress.getHostAddress();
            socket=new Socket();


        }
         @Override
         public void run() {
             try{
                 socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostAdd,8888),500);
                 sendRecieve=new SendRecieve(socket);
                 sendRecieve.start();

             }catch (IOException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Questions asking for reference to books or other external resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this  [API](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/)

Comment: u have any link?